# Block upload gif image renamed with png or jpg in PHP

Tags: php, image

I've a upload system and the user only can upload *png* and *jpg* images, but, if user rename the *gif* image with *.png*, for example, the system upload the gif image normally, so, how to do to block the *gif* images and others extensions that are not *png* or *jpg*? My code:

```
$imageNameBefore = $_FILES["the_image"]["name"];
$imageNameBeforeExt = basename($nomeImgAntes);
$imageNameExt = pathinfo($imageNameBeforeExt, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowedExt = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

if(!in_array($imageNameExt, $allowedExt )) {
    echo "Only images with extensions jpg or png are accepted!";
} else {
    $imageNameTmp = $_FILES["the_image"]["tmp_name"];
    $imageNameDir = "../photos";

    $nameImageEnd = md5($imageNameTmp).$imageNameExt;
    move_uploaded_file($imageNameTmp, ($imageNameDir.$nameImageEnd));

    imagedestroy($imageNameTmp);
}
```

Comment: so far what have you tried?

Comment: I'm going to try with imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecreatefrompng functions

Comment: Is this the full function of your code? are you using any framework?

Comment: Not using framework, pure php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insteadof checking the file name check the contents of the file by either "parsing" the entire contents (i.e. loading the image e.g. into gd) or via magic bytes (i.e. some parts of the file that must be present and contain specific values to have at least a chance of being a valid png/jpeg image).

see
 - http://docs.php.net/function.finfo-file
 - http://docs.php.net/function.imagecreatefromjpeg
 - http://docs.php.net/function.imagecreatefrompng